# Compare columns and extract entire row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets.

```
     Sheet 1

A        B        C
Batman Badcredit cool
Jiren  Bad credit not so cool
Goku   Goodcredit dangerously                 
lego   Bad credit bossy cool
bulma  Goodcredit could be cool

      Sheet 2

A        B        C
Jiren  Bad credit not so cool
bulma  Goodcredit could be cool
Waldo  no credit  floppy woppy
nemo   goodcredit dangerously
```

I want a third sheet with the records of Sheet 2 which aren't present in Sheet 1.

```
A        B        C
Waldo  no credit  floppy woppy 
nemo   goodcredit dangerously
```

Formula or code to help???
I am only able to pull column A values with the Match function when I have both column A on a single sheet.

Comment: Do you need a formula, or would a macro work? You could, alternatively, combine both sheets' data onto sheet three, then use the built-in "Remove Duplicates" (assuming you won't have data on sheet 1 that aren't in Sheet2).

Comment: A formula would be nice, remove duplicates wouldn't do well because I want matching to be done using column A and would like to pull the whole row of the unique entries, not clear on how I would do this with Remove Duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

One option is, in your Sheet2, use an `Index/Match` as an array formula.

I used a named range, `Sheet1Col1` is column A in Sheet1, `Sheet1Col2` is Sheet1 column 2, etc.

In your Sheet2, Column D, you can do:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1Col1,MATCH(A1&B1&C1,Sheet1Col1&Sheet2Col2&Sheet3Col3,0))
```

[image]

(enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd> and drag down).  Where you have a `#N/A`, that value doesn't exist on Sheet1.  You can do with that what you please, i.e. filter out, remove individually, etc.

So you can either make your own named ranges, or use say `Sheet1!A1:A10&Sheet1!B1:B10&Sheet1!C1:C10` or what have you.

Comment: Thank you sir, not ever hero wears a cape!

Comment: @phantom144 - Did that work for you? There are other ways you can do this, but I'm willing to bet (without VBA) this would be one of the quicker ways.  (PS: You can mark as the Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post, if it solved your question).

Comment: Not exactly, modified it a little and used this formula         `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($B$2:$B$22000,$A$2:$A$22000,0)),B2,"")` which matched against names, and returned the unique member from Sheet 2, unsure on how do I get all the values in the row attached to it.